# I want to change the version of strapi from v4 to v3.6.x

Tags: strapi

I have already done the setup for v4 `strapi` but now I wanted to change it to `v3.6.x`
and I am not able to find out how to do it.
Also I want to make sure that  it does not get auto updated. So any clue and answer is always appreciated.
If you need any details please let me know.

Comment: I have gone through various docs but didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basic but you have to keep it in mind that you  have to do it in the beginning while you are creating your `admin panel`.

&&

I am  working on  `linux` ,

**command:**

```
npx create-strapi-app@latest my-project --quickstart
```

you have to replace the `latest` with the version you want

**example:**

`npx create-strapi-app@3.6.2 my-project --quickstart`